# How to split a string and new line using strtok

Tags: c, string, token

I am trying to split my string and the (\n)new line and want to get the new string without \n.My code is as below.Thanks.

```
token = strtok(NULL,"")
```

The above snippet will store "some string and \n" where as I need just "some string".

My data looks like this.

```
1,v1,p1,182,1665,unkn
```

Comment: Use std::string and the algorithms to do it in C++. Much safer.

Comment: @Daniel It is printing NULLS

Comment: You should look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c to see how to do this in C++.

Comment: @SOaddict You have done a `strtok(your_string, separators);` before that? The `NULL` as first argument is for calls to `strtok` after the first. And you must of course check whether `token` is `NULL`, at which point you've reached the end of the input string.

Comment: Yes I am at the end of my input string.My data looks like this "1,v1,p1,182,1665,unkn".I am trying to extract "unkn" from this input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you data looks like this

```
char line[] = "1,v1,p1,182,1665,unkn\n";
```

you could do something like this (in C)

```
char* p = line + strlen(line) - 1;
for (;*p != ','; --p) 
{
  ;
}
char* lastword = strtok(p + 1,"\n");
```

Comment: That's valid C99, but many compilers will prefer the `lastword` declared at the top (but still assigned at the bottom, of course).

Comment: And it would be better to use a standard function like `strrchr` to find the last comma.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is replacing the first newline then this is much better:

```
char *tmp = strchr (str, '\n');
if (tmp) *tmp = 0;
```

If you are replacing the last newline in the string then this is better:

```
char *tmp = strrchr (str, '\n');
if (tmp) *tmp = 0;
```